# web3.exceptions.ValidationError: with tuple[], address, bytes

Tags: web3.py, calldata

Getting the following validation error and could not point to why

```
Could not identify the intended function with name `z`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'list'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'bytes'>)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `z`: ['z(tuple[],address,bytes)']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.
```

Here if function signature of the contract

```
function z(Tx[] memory d, address payable addr, bytes calldata data) public onlyOwners;
```

Using the following web3.py code

```
tx = []
addr = "0x..."
data = "...."
data = data.encode()       <--- Tried with and without this

contract.functions.z(tx, addr, data).buildTransaction({...})
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Edit: Added struct Tx definition

```
struct Bundle {
    address user;
    address token;
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 nonce;
    uint256 expiration;
}

struct Tx {
    Bundle bundle;
    uint8 v;
    bytes32 r;
    bytes32 s;
}
```

Comment: What is `Tx[]` in the function declaration?

Comment: Added it, missed it earlier.

Comment: So I found the problem to be in how I compute v, r, s
I have the signature from using ethersjs which is 132 characters long of the form

"0x67e22f7948121fc5b0723d2379cace121a8c2f8fc9542aed20ef1cc605741c366f1377c5f0a7305b6365ad604376b55070fe2867f71db0bf6c64b9a7b47e34cd1b"

I don't know how to compute v, r, s. Looks like doing the same thing as used by ethersjs doesn't work.

Comment: The first 64 characters are r, the next 64 are and the last 2 are v (it is 130 without considering the prefix 0x).

Comment: Yes that part was clear. Although calling the function required converting it using
`r = Web3.toBytes(hexstr="0x" + signature[2:66])` and `s = Web3.toBytes(hexstr="0x" + signature[66:130])` rather than directly using them.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that r, s values did not conform to bytes32.

Passing the following did not work.

```
signature = "0x........"
r = "0x" + signature[2:66]
s = "0x" + signature[66:130]
```

Instead had to convert the `r` and `s` values to bytes32

```
signature = "0x........"
r = Web3.toBytes(hexstr="0x" + signature[2:66])
s = Web3.toBytes(hexstr="0x" + signature[66:130])
```